# Putty fatal error - out of memory

Tags: putty

I am trying to ssh in a linux box using putty and getting "Putty fatal error" message box where the note in the message box is "Out of memory". I can login into the same box using WinSCP successfully. The port I am using in Putty is 22. Also I am able to connect using SmarTTY, but failing with putty.

Comment: can you get another version of putty to try.. maybe an earlier or later version

Comment: Again, what version of PuTTY and WinSCP are you using?

Comment: I was using putty 0.62, tried with putty 0.65 but same error. WinSCP version I am using 5.7.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [PuTTY FAQ](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-outofmem), there are a couple of possibilities:

- [the SSH version](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc//Chapter10.html#errors-memory) is incompatible with PuTTY
- [a bug in PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-outofmem) (possibly).

Comment: Yes the issue was I had configured an extremely large number of lines of scrollback in my terminal. It resolved after setting rows=80 and columns=24.